# using Retrofit:2.0 with Okhttp ( interceptors )

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I have an issue trying to use Okhttp with retrofit. I seem not to understand what I am doing wrong.

It gives showing up error: `'Anonymous class derived from Callback' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onResponse(Response<T>, Retrofit)' in 'Callback'`

In my MainActivity I have this:

```
    OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
            httpClient.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
                  @Override
                  public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
                          Request original = chain.request();

                          Request request = original.newBuilder()
                          .header("User-Agent", "Your-App-Name")
                          .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                          .header("Authorization","authorization_code")
                          .method(original.method(), original.body())
                          .build();

                          return chain.proceed(request);
                     }
            });


        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(httpClient)
                .build();
        TestInterface service = retrofit.create(TestInterface.class);



            Call<TestData> call = service.getPost();
/* It keeps pointing at this line below: 
'Callback' must either be declared abstract" */

            call.enqueue(new Callback<TestData>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Response<TestData> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                    // Get result Repo from response.body()
                    // response.isSuccess() is true if the response code is 2xx
                    int statusCode = response.code();
                    if (response.isSuccess()) {
                          System.out.println("Success: ");
                    } else {

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                    System.out.println("failed: "+t);
                }
            });
```

In my TestData Interface,I have this

```
public interface TestInterface {

    @POST("/paths_to_web_directory")
    Call<TestData>
    getPost();
}
```

This is the way i see it done in other examples, So maybe i'm implementing it the wrong way. Kindly correct me. Thanks

Comment: Which retrofit version are you using? Can you try removing the second parameter from onResponse?

Comment: I am using retrofit:2.0.0-beta2

Comment: You mean I should remove "Retrofit retrofit" ?

Answer (score 0):

The retrofit github project has a sample with a different method signature. Try this:

```
    call.enqueue(new Callback<TestData>() {    
        @Override public void onResponse(Call<TestData> call, Response<TestData> response) {  
        }
        @Override public void onFailure(Call<TestData> call, Throwable t) {
         }
});
```

Comment: It doesn't compile at all, saying cannot resolve <T> , I guess i would just have to fall back to Retrofit 1 using it with Okhttp and interceptors

Comment: No, just replace T with your type; TestData. See updated answer.